# How come I see a manage_categories capability but not a manage_tags capability for any users?

Tags: capabilities

Using plugins like "Members" or "Capability Manager", I don't see any such `manage_tags` capability. Shouldn't there be one like there is `manage_categories`?

EDIT: I think I figured it out. manage_terms is for all taxonomies. There isn't one specifically for tags, but I could create one if I so desire. This could allow me to set up a role that can edit only categories, but not tags, and vice versa.

NOTE: I got rated down. If you rate me down, *please state why*. Thanks.

Comment: Whoever rated me down, why? It doesn't help to get rated down without an explanation.

Comment: I figured it out. manage_terms applies to all taxonomies. I can make one specifically for tags if I like. Whoever rated me down should have said that...

Comment: Sorry you got voted down, makes no sense. Codex doesn't have answers and the output of Capability Manager, at least, is extremely confusing on this subject (from what I can tell "Manage Categories" controls everything add/edit/delete for both categories and tags, which is insane)

Comment: @jerclarke Are you sure that `manage_categories` will also give you the capability to manage tags?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out codex page regarding [**roles and caps**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) to see the list of default capabilites that exist, you can always create your own [**custom capabilites**](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/#add-capability)

Comment: That reference seems to be woefully out of date. It has nothing about tags, despite Capability Manager plugin having several tag-specific capabilities. This question deserves a meaningful answer about what exact default capabilities apply to categories, tags and terms and that reference doesn't have it.